# Firebase Push Notification Not Popping Up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, firebase-notifications

I successfully registered firebase service worker with

```
let messaging = null;
export const registerFirebaseServiceWorker = () => {
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
     console.log("serviceWorker in navigator");
     navigator.serviceWorker.register(("./firebase-messaging-sw.js"))
         .then((registration) => {
           console.log("Registration successful, scope is: ", registration.scope);
         })
  }
}
```

and try to receive the message with **messaging.onMessage** callback

```
    if (supportsWebPush) {
                    messaging.onMessage(payload => {
                        console.log("There's a message!", payload);
    
                        const notificationTitle = "notificationTitle"
                        const notificationOptions = {
                            body: payload
                        };
    
                        //self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
    
                        navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration("./firebase-messaging-sw.js").then(registration => {
                            console.log("got the registration");
                            registration.showNotification('Hello world!');
                        }).catch(error => {
                            console.log("No service worker registered", error);
                        });
    
                    });
```

Even though console.log was working and registration.showNotification was executed, there were no push notification on my browser ? Why is this? I've been trying multiple different ways and search for many suspected issues but can't found a proper way to display default web push pop up

Comment: Everything I implemented was mostly correct, problem was I disabled notifications on both browsers on both of my computers... To anyone please also consider this case

Comment: worth to mention, for mac users, make sure you disable do not disturb mode